Regrssion notation in the context of projection
I have been conditioned to the typical regression notation $y=X\beta +u$ where $X$ is a matrix and the rest are Nx1 vectors. In a book I was reading, they used the notation $y=b'x+u$ without specifying dimensions of any sort. They further stated that $proj(y|x)=b'x=(xx')^{-1}yx'x$.
However, this is quite confusing to me I am very accustomed to $\beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$ and given how confused I am, I am unable to derive $b$ by minimizing the sum of squared residuals using this notation.
Any references to external material that uses some sort of similar notation would be helpful. Otherwise a quick explanation about how this is possible to come up with this or a quick derivation specifying the dimensions would be extremely helpful.
